# Вывод большого текстового файла с возможностью редактирования

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

**Updated 11.02.16**

Как можно отобразить большой (несколько сотен мегабайт) текст в форме?
`TextBox` и `RichTextBox` не справляются с подобным объемом.

Вот простые примеры кода для демонстрации:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    sb.Append(i);
    sb.Append('\n');
}
this.textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Цикл формирования строки выполняется достаточно быстро (секунды), однако на передаче текста в TextBox, все встает намертво, терпения хватило минут на 5, потом остановил принудительно.

```
string[] lines = string[10000000];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    lines[i] = i.ToString();
}
this.textBox1.Lines = lines;
```

Результат аналогичный

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    sb.Append(i);
    sb.Append('\n');
}
this.richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Результат немного лучше, контрол заполняется и даже отрисовывается, но при скроле текста также замерзает после первой сотни строк.

Проблемы две:

- организация буфера, удобного для операций чтения/записи в файл и редактирования в `TextBox`-е;
- организация правильной работы вертикального скрола `TextBox`-а с учетом величины файла, а не только отображаемого фрагмента.

"Раскопки" в документации не дали ни какого полезного результата. Пока возникла только одна идея: прочитать файл в массив строк и отдавать порциями в TextBox, но при этом мне не понятно как заставить родной скрол `TextBox`-а отображать реальный объем файла и выполнять перемещение соответственно.

Другой вариант, строить свой "велосипед" с "Преферансом и Барышнями", но не хотелось бы, если есть решения для стандартных контролов. В любом случае, я не откажусь от идей как организовать редактирование текста и связанных с этим задач, вроде отслеживания и фиксации положения курсора в контроле.

EnSO также был перекопан в поисках ответа, одна из рекомендаций - использовать специальный софт для этого. Но если такой софт есть - значит задача все таки решаема.

Comment: А почему именно `TextBox`? Я не уверен насчёт WinForms, но в WPF `TextBox` не предназначен для огромных объёмов текста.

Comment: @VladD так больше нет ничего стандартного, ну кроме RichBox-а с возможностью редактирования. Я не исключаю что не стой стороны подхожу к проблеме, поэтому и спрашиваю тут. Возможно есть сторонние библиотеки, но это крайняя мера, если совсем ничего не придумается.

Comment: Наверное, можно вручную разбить на страницы, и показывать постранично. Это, конечно, суровый велосипед, придётся делать reflow после каждого изменения текста. Я не слышал о решении из коробки.

Comment: @VladD подождем, может кто сталкивался и готов поделиться. Ну или сам отпишусь когда победю

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием узнал, как решать такую задачу. Наверняка пригодится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант читать файл построчно и заполнять только по мере необходимости. 
На событие `onScroll` элемента `RichTextBox` навесить функцию, которая будет подгружать новые строки из файла. Пытаться загрузить большой файл целиком в какой-то контрол - это проблематично.

Например при работе с БД обычно либо используют Limit и подгружают по N строк, или грузят весь запрос (ограничено только оперативной памятью) в некий класс буфер, а потом подтягивают строки из него в `Grid` на форме.

Comment: Виртуализация, в общем. А что делать с позицией скроллинга?

Comment: Позицию отслеживать необязательно, просто подгружайте небольшими порциями (например по 10 строк, что бы не видно было фризов) при каждом событии скрола в низ до тех пор пока строки не кончатся.

Comment: Сложнее  с редактированием (если после этого файл потребуется сохранить). Единственный вариант это держать весь исходный файл в буфере, и после редактирования заменить в нем все загруженные строки на те что вы изменили в контроле на форме (Индекс строки полученной с буфера все равно сохранять будете для подгрузки строк).

Comment: ну и еще вариант найти кастомный контрол который поддерживает виртуализацию, сделаь класс буфер со всеми необходимыми методами и воспользоваться DataBinding

Comment: Хм, я имел в виду, что придётся как-то вручную устанавливать позицию внутреннему скроллбару. По умолчанию он исходит из того, что данные загружены полностью, и показывает позицию соответствующим образом.

Comment: Без виртуализации, судя по всему, не обойтись. Хотелось бы ещё обойтись без ручного reflow (переразбиения на строки при изменениях).

Comment: По моему если вы используете метод `Append` на `RichTextBox` скроллбар сам подстроиться под длину текста

Comment: Вы можете считать файл построчно например в `List` потом получить текст из `RichTextBox` в виде массива или того же списка и просто заменить им те строки которые были загружены из буфера (`List`). Разве что в файле "на пару сотен мегабайт" будет всего одна строка )) тогда надо его бить посимвольно как то...

Comment: Обычно одна строка в файле означает по сути один _абзац_, а разбиение на строки зависит от текущей ширины контрола: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J6F6z.png

Comment: По идее, при чтении файла построчно (не побитово), строка - это то что заканчивается символом новой строки `\n`. А то что у вас на скриншоте называется `Word wrapping`. И да, зачастую одна строка = один абзац

Comment: Да, видимо так и придется делать, Если больше ни кто ни чего не предложит, и внешний скрол вешать. Правда остается вопрос, как отследить положение курсора в выведенном фрагменте.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду положение курсора внутри контрола с загруженным текстом? По идее тут сложностей быть не должно...

Comment: Можно сделать и полностью прогружаемый, но то совсем велосипед с переопределением отрисовки текста. Теоретически можно было бы переопределить методы TB или RTB, но они используют нативный код внутри, так что это тоже может оказаться проблемой, но тут уже пробовать надо

Answer (score 0):

На [SOeN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498422/c-sharp-read-in-a-large-150mb-text-file-into-a-rich-text-box), в своё время предлагали вариант через `RichTextBox`, для файлов с большим размером

```
Use RichTextBox.LoadFile

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile.aspx

I'm not sure why you would want to load the entire text to a StringBuilder. 
Alternatively you could pass a FileStream to LoadFile which would render the large file 
for you.
```

(C) AB Kolan

Так же, как вариант, можно почитать рассуждения на [Social.MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8103b97a-ad61-486a-bad1-248c4c89cf0f/how-to-load-a-large-text-file-to-richtextbox?forum=winforms)

Comment: да я видел этот ответ. посмотрите внимательнее, в последнем примере кода как раз rtb. он тоже не осилил такой объем, увы

Comment: @rdorn У Вас хоть и `rtb` в последнем примере кода, но всё же, в том ответе указывается на то что, использовать попробовать не `StringBuilder()` а `.LoadFile`, а по поводу конкретно `StringBuilder()`, я предложил ссылку с рассуждениями, там в итоге в `rtb` файлы размером более 400mb придумали грузить по размерности байтов на страницу с дальнейшей подгрузкой при прокрутке

Comment: последнюю ссылку еще не видел, но в вопросе предложен аналогичный подход. к нему еще бы решить проблемы со скролом и буфером. буфер ладно, не велика проблема, со скролом хуже

Comment: @rdorn В вопросе то да, подход аналогичный, и он аналогично не работал, потому и предложили в ответе, попробовать использовать `.LoadFile`