# Подвисает RichTextBox если в него записать около 10 тысяч строк

Tags: c#, winforms, производительность

Мне нужна высокая производительность при редактировании больших текстовых файлов, использую компонент RichTextBox, записываю в него данные например так:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9000; i++)
{
   TextBoxEditor.Text += Guid.NewGuid() + ".\r\n";
}
```

После чего, при скроллинге компонента видно, что он подвисает, есть ли пути решения данной проблемы?

Похожие вопросы уже оказывается существуют, но ни в одном нет ответа, как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Не использовать контрол для того, для чего он не предназначен? Если вам нужно написать текстовый редактор, пишите текстовый редактор.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491141/198316 я уже выяснял это, так что присоединяюсь к мнению VladD

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях из файла по частям читают куски текста, с которыми в данный момент идёт работа.

Comment: VladD что вы имеете ввиду? Мне действительно нужно написать редактор, в котором объем данных, может свободно достигать подобного количества строк. Какой контрол посоветуете?

Comment: @lails: Никакой, такого контрола нет. Боюсь, вам придётся писать всё вручную.

Comment: @lails либо искать сторонний компонент. В коллекции DevExpress было что-то претендующее на возможности MS Word, но оно платное.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответы, мне действительно нужно было знать, что я не ошибаюсь с тем, что проблема в вкомпоненте.