# Через какое-то время медленно работает RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть форма, на ней RichTextBox, который отображает прогресс.

Т.е делается append сообщений вида : "Скопировано 1/100 файлов\n"

Так вот, когда кол-во строк достигает около 60 000, становится видно, что сообщения добавляются не сразу как в начале, а с задержкой.

Если его очистить, то скорость возвращается.

Неужели, 60 000 строк вызывают провисания?

Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос уже обсуждался: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491141/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528977/).

Вкратце -- винформсовский `RichTextBox` не предназначен для такого объема данных. Как бороться -- не выводить такой объем. Если это логи, то такой объем просто не нужен пользователю. Если это текстовый редактор -- выводить только часть содержимого и менять ее на скролле.

В вашем случае можно иметь всего одну строку и менять ее содержимое.